# desmontar objetos em um array

Tags: java, array, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Tenho um método de busca no banco que me traz o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que dentro do Objeto[4] vem mais um array que contem Pessoas, PessoasEnderecos..

eu gostaria que me retornasse apenas dessa forma e não dentro de outro array como está ocorrendo agora, deveria ficar assim:

```
elementData=Object[10](id=144)
[0]=Pessoas(id=166)
[1]=PessoasEnderecos(id=167)
...
```

Meu método está assim :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/pessoas")
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Pessoas>> buscarPessoas(HttpServletRequest request) throws  Exception { 

        String idEntidadeCrypt = request.getHeader("DataBase");
        Long idEntidade = Long.parseLong(Crypto.decode(idEntidadeCrypt));

        Collection<Pessoas> pessoasBuscados = pessoasService.buscarFiltro(idEntidade);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(pessoasBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

e o método que faz o meu select:

```
@Repository
public interface PessoasRepository extends JpaRepository<Pessoas, Integer> {

    @Query( value="select pes, pEnd, pFis, pJur "
            + "from "
            + "Pessoas pes, "
            + "PessoasEnderecos pEnd,"
            + "PessoasFisicas pFis,"
            + "PessoasJuridicas pJur"           
            + " where  "            
            + "pes.entidade.idEntidade = pEnd.entidade.idEntidade "
            + "and pes.idPessoa = pEnd.pessoa.idPessoa "
            + "and pes.entidade.idEntidade = pFis.entidade.idEntidade "
            + "and pes.idPessoa = pFis.pessoa.idPessoa "
            + "and pes.entidade.idEntidade = pJur.entidade.idEntidade "
            + "and pes.idPessoa = pJur.pessoa.idPessoa "
            + "and pes.entidade.idEntidade = :parametroId " )
    public  Collection<Pessoas>  encontrar(@Param("parametroId") Long usuarioEntidade);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receio que oque você quer não seja possível:

Na sua query você especifica que cada linha terá: pes, pEnd, pFis e pJur.

O Object[10] representa todas linhas retornadas.

O Object[4] representa uma linha do retorno e é exatamente o que você escreveu na query.

Não tem como uma query retornar uma linha diferente da outra...

Comment: Em MyBatis tem, não sei nesse repositório JPA. No MyBatis, se não me engano todas os objetos devem ser de classes que estendam da classe base retornada